# Java - Cron job - if an instance triggers a batch job, prevent other instance from doing the same

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, jpa, atomic

I have an application running on two instances and only communication between the instances is that they operate on a single database. I have few batch jobs running on it. For example: Copy records from the database to a file and deliver the file to a server. Since there is a common database for both the instances, I'm trying to write to a table that job has been triggered. Basically, a trigger condition is such a record doesn't exist on a given table. How can I perform this atomically, i.e., check the table that job hasn't been triggered then insert into table?

Comment: Use a transaction.

Comment: In my repository, I have getBy and save methods. Shall I check if getBy returns a null, call save method, and return true to trigger the batch job? And use @transactional annotation for this service method?

Comment: You need to begin a transaction. Select for update to lock the rows. Then carry out operations. A normal select won’t help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a scheduled task that needs to be launched, for example, every 15 seconds and should only run on a single instance of app, then you can use [ShedLock](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock)

It's pretty simple mechanism that basically does the same that you mentioned - creates a table (actually, you need to create it once) and periodically acquires lock for it. You can set up for how much time it should be locked and some others things.

Works with both SQL and NoSQL dbs, like Postgres and Mongo and requires just one annotation `@SchedulerLock`. See below:

```java
    @Scheduled(fixedRateString = "PT15S")
    @SchedulerLock(name = "copy_records")
    public void copyRecords()
    {
        // do smth on a single instance of an app only
    }
```

Comment: For scheduled jobs which are to run once a day, what would be fixedRateString?

Comment: The issue with this approach is that you only allow one instance of the task to run at a time.  Presumably, the reason for having multiple instances of the code performing the task, that is because you need the parallelism.  However, this approach works if all you do in the locked code is to lock the record, or possibly just to flag the record with an "I've got it" flag.  Then you have another task that isn't ShedLock'ed that is doing whatever the hard work was.  That way, the next instance isn't waiting for you to finish with the record, just for you to finish grabbing it.

Comment: @rohan it accepts [Duration-compatible strings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html?is-external=true#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-). So for "once a day" it would be `PT24H` or `P1D`. notice there is no "T" in second case. Or you can just use a regular Spring cron expression

Comment: Thanks! appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

**Pesimistic locking** can help here:

- Create a dedicated table that holds a lock record, with the last execution time
- In the scheduled execution, aquire (or create) the lock record over an injected `EntityManager` with `LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE`.
- Check the execution time on the lock record: if it was recently updated, the job must have already been run on another instance
- Otherwise, execute the job, and update the last execution time on the lock record afterwards.

See [Lock Modes (Java EE Tutorial)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkjiu.html) for more details an options.

Example application of such a locking mechanism: Liquibase's `DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK` table, documented [here](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/databasechangeloglock_table.html).